# как игнорировать знак $ в bash-скрипте?

Tags: ubuntu, bash

задача такая:
Превратить файл шаблона конфига nginx в готовый конфиг nginx.
в шаблоне встречаются такие записи как $uri и тд.

в скрипте используется только переменная $user

скрипт считает их за переменные и тупо не вписывает в файл.
есть идеи как это можно обойти?

Comment: Переписать скрипт?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно, например, «экранировать» символ `$`, добавляя перед ним `\`:

```
$ sed 's/\$/\\$/g' файл > новый.файл
```

и, если требуется, затем перед строкой `$user` этот символ убирать:

```
$ sed 's/\$/\\$/g;s/\\\$user/$user/g' файл > новый.файл
```